# How to plot circles with numpy and matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to graph 3 circles with different radii but with my code there is nothing being printed. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I am supposed to use numpy and matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta=np.arange(0,2*np.pi,360)
plt.plot(0.25*np.cos(theta),0.25*np.sin(theta),"g")
plt.axis("equal")
plt.plot(1*np.cos(theta),1*np.sin(theta),"--b")
plt.plot(2*np.cos(theta),2*np.sin(theta),"--r")
plt.show()
```

Comment: what you are plotting are points. you can check the values of theta it has only one value

Comment: You can still use `arange`, but the 3rd argument is the step size, not the number of points. If you want 360 points from 0 to 2pi, it should be `np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, np.pi/180)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change line4 to

```
theta=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
```

Comment: Thanks I put both the linspace and arange bc I was supposed to use arange unfortunately